# "The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your security settings." PPAM addin causing this error from Ribbon but not from Code

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some VBA PPT macros along with custom ribbon interface. Whose macros work fine from code but when made into ppam addin and added to PPT addins, some commands throw this error msg, however the macro works well, just want to stop this annoying msgs. The subs and functions are all Public and it still shows the same error. Please help

```
Public Sub frmFeedNotes_show()
frmFeedNotes.Show
End Sub

<!--RibbonX Visual Designer 1.94 for Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0. XML Code produced on 2017-10-06-->
<customUI  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" >
    <ribbon >
        <tabs >
            <tab 
                id="zenTools"
                label="Zen Tools"

                visible="true">

                <group 
                    id="FileProp"
                    label="File Properties"
                    visible="true">

                    <menu id="mnuExport" 
                        label="Export Slides" 
                        showImage="true"
                        imageMso="ExportToVCardFile" size="large">

                        <button id="btnFeedNotes"
                            label="Feed Notes*"
                            imageMso="FootnotesEndnotesShow"
                            onAction="frmFeedNotes_show" />
                        <button id="btnNotesCSV"
                            label="Notes as CSV"
                            imageMso="CommaSign"
                            onAction="ExportNotes" />
                    </menu>
                </group >

            </tab >
        </tabs >
    </ribbon >
</customUI >
```

Comment: It would help if you posted at least the subroutine that throws this error and the ribbonx code that triggers it. But possibly your ribbonx code is calling a sub/function that's not declared as Public.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46847859/edit) your **question itself** to show the code and any other information required to answer the question.  P.S.  I will remove the inappropriate [macro] tag from the question - the description specifically says that it is nothing to do with VBA.

Comment: i believe the macro works well when run directly from VBA editor but throws the error when calling from custom ribbon button, is that right?

Comment: @Rosetta: Yes, That's right . It gives this error only when running from the addin not from the code . Any ideas

Comment: I see. let me know if the answer works for you..

Answer (score 1):

Need to insert module name for onAction e.g. Module1

```
<button id="btnNotesCSV"
                        label="Notes as CSV"
                        imageMso="CommaSign"
                        onAction="Module1.ExportNotes" />
```

The ribbon Button also will pass a parameter to the sub, so expect it to receive a parameter. Add a parameter for the macro as follow

```
Public Sub frmFeedNotes_show(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
    frmFeedNotes.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rosetta, It posed like it would finally solve it, but still the same pestering msg appears to my disbelief. Checked both your fixes now, Unsure what else causes it. Besides, I have not added Module1. prefix nor the parameter in the sub to my other macros, they work just fine. this msg appears only on few macros.

Comment: please describe ur problem clearly so we are able to help

Comment: Hi Rosetta, I have made the 2 suggested fixes: supplying parameter (ByVal control As IRibbonControl) and also adding onAction="Module1.ExportNotes", still the same error msg appears. it doesnt appear on few other macros where i have not done these 2 fixes, so dont know what causes these error msgs. please help

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Not able to solve it. @Jegan, please post in case you got it resolved.